# extending lambert material, opacity not working

Tags: three.js

i would like to create a custom material which extends the lambert shader but setting the mesh translucent doesn't work.

```
var shaders = { lambert : THREE.ShaderLib['lambert'] }

materials.mylambert = function(parameters){

  var vertexShader = shaders.mylambert.vertexShader
   , fragmentShader = shaders.mylambert.fragmentShader
   , uniforms = shaders.mylambert.uniforms
   , attributes = {}

   var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( 
    { vertexShader: vertexShader
    , fragmentShader: fragmentShader
    , uniforms: uniforms
    , lights : true
    , fog : true
    } )

    material.setValues( parameters )
    return material  
}
var material = new materials.mylambert({ opacity : 0.4, transparent : true } )
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material)
```

Comment: What is your ultimate objective? Do you want to add new uniforms or modify existing ones? Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: yea i would like to modifiy existing ones and also add new ones, but at first i would like to get it to behave like the original lambert material and then work from there.

Comment: one of my objectives would be to pass an int between 0-255 to the vertex shader for the color instead of 4 float32 per vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate properties of the material from the material uniforms. You can get your specific example to work like so:

```
var shaders = { mylambert : THREE.ShaderLib[ 'lambert' ] };

var materials = {};

materials.mylambert = function( parameters, myUniforms ) {

    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

        vertexShader: shaders.mylambert.vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: shaders.mylambert.fragmentShader,
        uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.merge( [ shaders.mylambert.uniforms, myUniforms ] ),
        attributes: {}

    } );

    material.setValues( parameters )

    return material;

};

myProperties = {
    lights: true,
    fog: true,
    transparent: true
};

myUniforms = {
    opacity: { type: "f", value: 0.4 },
};

var material = new materials.mylambert( myProperties, myUniforms );
```

three.js r.58