# ThreeJS - Extend Lambert Shader with Custom VertexShader

Tags: three.js, shader

I want to adapt this Shader here:
https://aerotwist.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-shaders-part-2/
to a standard Lambert or Phong that it works with all my Lights in the Scene.

My current state is that I extend the Lambert with this code:

```
    var attributes = {
    displacement: {
        type: 'f', // a float
        value: [] // an empty array
    }
};

var uniforms = {
    amplitude: {
        type: 'f', // a float
        value: 0
    }
};

var shaders = { mylambert : THREE.ShaderLib[ 'lambert' ] };

var materials = {};

materials.mylambert = function( parameters, myUniforms ) {

    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

        vertexShader:  $('#vertexLambert').text(),
        fragmentShader: shaders.mylambert.fragmentShader,
        uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.merge( [ shaders.mylambert.uniforms, myUniforms ] ),
        attributes :attributes,
        lights:true,
        shading:THREE.FlatShading

    } );

    material.setValues( parameters );

    return material;

};

var myProperties = {
    lights: true,
    fog: true,
    transparent: true
};

var myMaterial = new materials.mylambert( myProperties, uniforms );
```

Which I got from this Post:
[extending lambert material, opacity not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421575/extending-lambert-material-opacity-not-working)

The vertexShader is basically the shape as shaders.mylambert.vertexShader but with the additional code from the shader example on top.

It works somehow, so the vertices move, but the faces didn't shade when they change their shape so they always have the same shader when I use a plane for example as a the mesh.

In short;
I need a Lambert/Phong Shader that manipulates the Vertices over time up and down to simulate a low Poly Water surface.

Comment: So you are wanting water in three.js? Have you seen [this](https://github.com/jbouny/ocean)

Comment: That's too Complex. We want a low poly Surface that just "Wobble" a bit up and down with their Vertices :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is still relevant, You can solve this issue much simpler:

1. Have your model render with a Lambert, Phong, Standard or whatever lit material you like.
2. Create another `Scene`, `Camera` and a `WebGLRenderTarget`, create a plane and apply your ShaderMaterial to it. Position your camera so that the plane fits exactly your entire frame of the scene.
3. Render the other `Scene` to the `WebGlRenderTarget` and apply it as a map to your original Lambert material this way:

```
    let mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        map: renderTarget.texture
    })
```

Viola! You now have a fully lit ShaderMaterial as you like.