# How do you "combine"a ShaderMaterial and LambertMaterial?

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, vertex-shader

First, thank you so much for this great work and community.

I am trying to write a simple low poly style water material.

I know there are different ways of writing this kind of thing, and I would like as much as possible to do it in a js script (I come from C# dev', and I am not super comfy with frontend yet).

The one way I can understand after hours of compiling infos on the Net is this one:

```
var waterVertexShader =  
                "attribute float vertexDisplacement;" +
                "uniform float time;" +
                "varying vec3 vUv;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "   vUv = position;" +
                "   vUv.y += sin(time) * 0.01;" +
                "   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(vUv, 1.0);"+     
                "}"
            ;

            var waterFragmentShader =

                "void main() {" +
                "gl_FragColor = vec4(0.65, 0.88, 1, 1);" +
                "}";


                },
                flatShading : true,
                vertexShader: waterVertexShader,
```

That gives me the beginning of the wanted behavior, but this is not my issue.

Now, if I want to inherit let's say the Lambert or Phong material properties, what is the right way to proceed?

It sounds very basic, but this is the only relevant link I found:
[ThreeJS - Extend Lambert Shader with Custom VertexShader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309519/threejs-extend-lambert-shader-with-custom-vertexshader)
and there is no answer.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways to enhance a built-in material in `three.js`:

- You can use the callback [Material.onBeforeCompile()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/Material.onBeforeCompile). This approach is demonstrated in the following [example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_modified). If you want to add just minor enhancements to the shader code, this should be your first choice.
- Create a custom material with `RawShaderMaterial` or `ShaderMaterial` from scratch and reuse the existing shader chunks from the library. This approach is very flexible but it requires good knowledge about the internals of `three.js`'s material system.
- Of course you could modify/monkey patch the existing shader chunks but this approach is in general to recommended (you effectively change the library code with all consequences).
- Another approach is to use the promising but experimental `NodeMaterial`. However, this technique is not documented and no part of the core so far. There are some examples that demonstrate the usage like this [one](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_nodes).

Comment: Thank you, I went for the onBeforeCompile option (I've just spent one full week trying to implement a raycaster solution, I'm a bit tired), and it works like a charm.

I can't thumb you up because I'm too fresh here, but you know my hearts does!

Comment: I also read pailhead's article, whose comment disappeared.
Not sure to understand why, but anyway, thank you too, buddy.

Comment: Probably because it was a so called "link-only" answer. It's more correct to put this link to the comments.

Comment: BTW: Please accept the answer^^. This should be possible even for new users.

Comment: Here is the link: https://medium.com/@pailhead011/extending-three-js-materials-with-glsl-78ea7bbb9270